# m2e and Groovy-Eclipse plugins for Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, groovy-eclipse

In order to solve the following Maven pom.xml import error:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.0:execute ...    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

I'm trying to install https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse Groovy-Eclipse 
plugin.

When I do this I see the following solution at Eclipse install window:

[image]

Groovy-Eclipse won't work with m2e plugin for a some reason.
What can be a reason of this and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Groovy-Eclipse M2E integration* feature includes the *Eclipse m2e* feature. If you complete the installation, you should see the Maven integration feature nested under Groovy-Eclipse M2E in the Installation Details dialog.